# Find one occurence of substring using suffix array

Tags: python, list, search, binary-search, suffix-array

I'm trying to figure out how to **binary search** in **suffix array** for one occurence of pattern. 
Let's have a text: `petertomasjohnerrnoerror`. 
I try to find `er`.

`SA` is a suffix array of this text: `8,14,19,3,1,12,10,7,13,17,18,11,6,22,0,23,16,21,15,20,4,9,2,5`

Now, I want to find any index of suffix array, which value pointing at one `'er'`. So the output would be index in SA pointing at `3,14 or 19` so it would return 1,2 or 3

I'm trying to use a binary search but I can't figure out how.

```
def findOneOccurence(text,SA,p):
    high = len(text)-1           # The last index
    low = 0                      # the lowest index
    while True:
        check = (high-low)/2     # find a middle

        if p in text[SA[check]:SA[check]+len(p)]:
            return check
        else:
            if text[SA[check]:SA[check]+len(p)]<p:
                low = check
            else:
                high = check
        if high<=low:
            return None
```

This returns `11`. But `text[SA[11]:SA[11]+2]` is `'oh'` instad of `'er'`.
Where could be the problem?

This function would work on huge texts about millions of chars.

EDIT: I've found a mistake. Instead of if `text[SA[check]:SA[check+len(p)]]<p:` should be `text[SA[check]:SA[check]+len(p)]<p:` but it's still wrong. It returns None instead of `'er'`

EDIT II: Another mistake: if high>=low changed to high<=low, now, it returns 2 which is good.

EDIT III: Now it works, but on some inputs it gets to the loop and never ends.

Comment: Did you get `re` and `er` mixed up?

Comment: @yes, I mean 'er' because 're' is not in the text, thanks

Comment: I don't think you are finding the middle the right way. Shouldn't it be `(high+low)/2` instead of `(high-low)/2`?

Comment: Thanks, it was another mistake. It's almost done :)

Comment: Instead of `in` you should just use `==`

Answer (score 2):

Borrowing and editing https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/bisect.py

```
>>> text= 'petertomasjohnerrnoerror'
>>> SA = 8,14,19,3,1,12,10,7,13,17,18,11,6,22,0,23,16,21,15,20,4,9,2,5
>>> def bisect_left(a, x, text, lo=0, hi=None):
    if lo < 0:
        raise ValueError('lo must be non-negative')
    if hi is None:
        hi = len(a)
    while lo < hi:
        mid = (lo+hi)//2
        if text[a[mid]:] < x: lo = mid+1
        else: hi = mid
    if not text[a[lo]:].startswith(x): 
        # i suppose text[a[lo]:a[lo]+len(x)] == x could be a faster check
        raise IndexError('not found')
    return a[lo]

>>> bisect_left(SA, 'er', text)
14
```